# Encrypt using 3DES EDE / ECB / NOPadding

Tags: c#, php, encryption, 3des

I have received a task to encrypt and decrypt an XML string by using a TOKEN and a KEY.
The encryption shall use `3DES EDE / ECB / NOPadding` and can be made either in `PHP` or `C#`

I am not so prepared on this so I have read around a bit of theory and came to a very easy implementation which is as follow:

```
public string Encrypt( string message, string key, string token ) {
    byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( message );
    byte[] keyArray = CreateHash( key );
    byte[] vectorArray = CreateHash( token );
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    //set the secret key for the tripleDES algorithm
    tdes.Key = keyArray;
    //mode of operation. there are other 4 modes. We choose ECB(Electronic code Book)
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    //padding mode(if any extra byte added)
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor(keyArray, vectorArray);
    //transform the specified region of bytes array to resultArray
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock( toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length );
    //Release resources held by TripleDes Encryptor
    tdes.Clear();
    //Return the encrypted data into unreadable string format
    return Convert.ToBase64String( resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length );
}

private byte[] CreateHash( string toHash ) {
    //use get hashcode regards to your key
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashKey = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] kArray = hashKey.ComputeHash( UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( toHash ) );
    //Always release the resources and flush data
    //of the Cryptographic service provide. Best Practice
    hashKey.Clear();
    return kArray;
}
```

However I think this is not completely correct. In fact I am not sure that the TOKEN shall be used this way.
Can somebody provide more informations and point me to the right direction on how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the 'token' and what is it for?

Comment: @GregS: The TOKEN is a string of text which is 10 characters long. The task says to encrypt a message with `3DES/ECB/NOPadding` by using a Key and a Token. The key is a string like "123456789012345678901234" (24 characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use token as a vector on TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider, together with the key.

```
ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor(key, token);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my code by adding a new hash of the TOKEN and used as you've suggested. Did you meant that way?

Comment: Yes, I meant that way :)